# Visual Studio 2010 - Extracting YEAR from a parameter with date

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, parameters

The objective is to set a parameter that allows anyone to enter a year in order
to display sales for that year.

This is the code I entered into the 'Database Properties' area.

```
SELECT
    st.Name AS Region, st.SalesYTD AS Sales, YEAR(so.OrderDate) AS OrderYear        
FROM                
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS so  
LEFT OUTER JOIN     
    Sales.SalesTerritory AS st ON so.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID 
WHERE               
    DATEPART(YEAR, so.OrderDate)=@OrderDate
```

When I opened 'Preview', the following error came up.

How do I rewrite this code to make it run smoothly?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `...DATEPART(YEAR,so.OrderDate)=DATEPART(YEAR,@OrderDate)`?

Comment: `DATEPART(Year, so.Orderdate)` returns an **`int`** - which cannot really be compared to `@OrderDate` which most likely is a `DATETIME` or `DATE` - right??

Comment: Also: why are you using `YAER(so.OrderDate)` in the column list, and `DATEPART(YEAR, so.OrderDate)` in the `WHERE` clause? They both do the same - pick one and use one - any one - but use just one of the two approaches (it's all about **consistency**)

Comment: THANK YOU, IAN! It worked as you specified. The only thing is that the TIME,DAY and MONTH are still attached. I prefer only the YEAR. Let me know if you have any ideas on that. Meanwhile I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT
    st.Name AS Region, st.SalesYTD AS Sales, YEAR(so.OrderDate) AS OrderYear
FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS so
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Sales.SalesTerritory AS st ON so.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID 
WHERE
    DATEPART(YEAR,so.OrderDate)=DATEPART(YEAR,@OrderDate)

As suggested by Ian Preston